# Are there any thread managers java

Tags: java

I have been making a threadmanager class in java and wanted it so you could input a class and it would run the threadrun method in that class but when I write my code my ide says:cannot find symbol threadrun

Code:

```
package thenetwork;

/**
 *
 * @author Jman
 */
public class Threadmanager implements Runnable
{
    Class clas;
    Object parameter1 = null;
    public Threadmanager(Class classobj)
    {
        clas = classobj;
    }
    public Threadmanager(Class classobj, Object param1)
    {
        clas = classobj;
        parameter1 = param1;
    }
    public void run() {
        if(parameter1 != null)
        {
            clas.threadrun(parameter1);
        }
        else
        {
            clas.threadrun();
        }
    }

}
```

If this is not clear comment it and I will edit my post
Edit:I need this class to be able to run multiple types of other classes

Comment: Your question body conflicts with your question title, so I'll only answer the question title and leave others to answer the trivial compilation error mentioned in the question body: check the [`java.util.concurrent` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) ([tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html))

Comment: java.until.Class doesn't have a threadrun method. I would recommend you look into java.util.concurrent as BalusC recommended

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.Class doesn't have a method called threadrun.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you want this "thread manager" class to do, but for your information, this is the way that you launch a thread in Java:

```
Thread th = new Thread(runnable);
th.start();
```

This will create and start a new thread, and the thread will execute the code of the `Runnable` supplied as an argument.

The `Runnable` interface does not directly provide a way to pass a parameter into the `run()` method, but you can achieve the same effect by implementing other methods, implementing a constructor or by coding the `run` method to retrieve a value from an enclosing scope (if it is implemented as an inner class ...)

---

To answer the question expressed in the Question title: yes Java does have standard thread managers, and there are also third-party libraries that implement this kind of thing.  I'd recommend that you read the tutorial that @BalusC linked to ... and don't try to implement your own thread manager / thread pool.

Comment: I know how to run a thread i just want to make a class that when given input it can run methods from other classes

Comment: @Javaman - as I said, your best bet is to use an existing thread manager.  A thread will not directly run methods from other classes.  You need to implement a `Runnable` that does this.

Answer (score 2):

There are lower-level constructs, like `Thread` that you can use, but I recommend starting with an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). It handles most common threading needs, in a safe and robust manner.

Comment: +1 for the ExecutorService. Don't roll your own. The Java concurrency utilities are awesome. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

Threadrun isn't an function of [class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an invocation of `newInstance()` against your class argument.  If you try to reference the class object directly, you're only going to be able to use methods available to the type `Class` rather than the type of class your object represents.  Your class should probably look something like (I've left out the parameter logic):

```
public class Threadmanager implements Runnable {
  MyThreadRunObject object;

  public Threadmanager(Class classobj) {
    object = (MyThreadRunObject) classobj.newInstance();
  }
  ...
  public void run() {  
    object.threadrun();
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you're using Java 1.5+, I'd generify your class argument.  The nice thing about generifying it is that you can do a bounded generic type of `T extends ThreadRunnable` and put your threadrun method in an interface, allowing you to restrict the types your `ThreadManager` class would take as a class argument.

Comment: This would work but what if I have many a lot of classes i want to use like 100